# How to simultaneously (PHP) curl a file being uploaded by AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, curl

I have a form which allows users to upload large video files to a 3rd party API endpoint. The API expects the api key as one of the parameters, so in order to keep it protected, I submit the form to a PHP script and the PHP script sends the file to the API using curl. This works, but the problem is that it means the file gets uploaded twice: once to my php script, then again from the PHP script to the API. Is there a way to do the two in parallel? In other words, let the curl script start uploading BEFORE the ajax upload is complete?

Comment: It would still get uploaded twice, once to your server and then from your server to the remote api, just that both uploads are happening at the same time rather than one after the other. How are you uploading the files to your server as you can't use POST etc as POSTed files are not available until the request completes. Only method I can see working as you describe is to create a proxy that appends the missing api key

Comment: You'll have a hard time doing that with a standard Apache/PHP setup, since Apache handles the upload before PHP ever gets asked. A custom proxy/webserver that immediately "forwards" the uploaded data with added headers could do this, but probably not PHP.

Comment: Thanks guys. This is helpful. I've never set up a custom proxy/webserver. Can you point me somewhere to look into it?

Comment: do you want to start curl when ajax process  complete?

Comment: @sudhakar No. I *don't* want to wait for AJAX to complete.

Answer (score 1):

If you change from post to put you could use

```
$input = fopen('php://input','r');
```

And then fread it likes standard large file and then send the partial chunks with curl ?

You will need to use CURLOPT_READFUNCTION to pass it in chunks.

Be aware if the user stops for what ever reason you will need to clean up the missing files

I'm not sure of a way using post

Small example

set curl up with this option

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, functionCall));


function functionCall($ch, $data){
 global $input;
 return fread($input, $length);

}
```

$length is the amount of data sent in each chunk. The suer will have to upload at least that amount before the upload starts

8192 is a popular length, Give that a go

Comment: That's an intriguing idea! Do I have to manage the chunks or do they happen automatically?

Comment: you will have to manage but it will just be passing the argument to fread